# Calling setTimeout function in a loop not work

Tags: jquery

I need to add class to a span elements but during some period.

```
jQuery('.rating').each(function(){
    var datarating = $(this).attr("rating");
    for(var i=0; i<datarating; i++){
        (function (i) {
         setTimeout(function () {                
            rating(this, i);
         }, 1000, i);
        })(i);
    }
}); 

function rating(obj, i){    
    $(obj).find('span').eq(i).addClass('rated');
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="rating" rating="2">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>   
</div>
<div class="rating" rating="3">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>   
</div>
```

What I do wrong. I could not call setTimeout function in a loop In the end of the script the result must be.

```
<div class="rating" rating="2">
    <span class="rated"></span>
    <span class="rated"></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>   
</div>
<div class="rating" rating="3">
    <span class="rated"></span>
    <span class="rated"></span>
    <span class="rated"></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery('.rating').each(function(){
    var rating = this;
    var datarating = $(this).attr("rating");
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
       if ( i <  datarating ) {            
           rating(rating, i);
           i++;
       } else {
           clearInterval(interval);
       }
    }, 1000, i);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a suggested edit and I thought it might be an issue, but I guess not!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, `this` does not exist in the scope of setTimeout. You should rather store the global reference and then use it inside.Try this:

```
 Variables.obj = this;
 Variables.ResizeTimer = setTimeout(
     function(){
        rating(Variables.obj, i);
     },
     1000
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that "this" is bound to window is your problem.

you would be best in this case to use the old that = this trick to take a reference to the correct this and invoke the rating function with that.

its not clear from your example why you need the timeout either ?